# Wrapping the design library navigation drawer in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-design-library, navigation-drawer

Is there an (easy) way to wrap the navigation drawer view (more precisely `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`) from the design support library in a Fragment?

The motivation behind this is to move navigation drawer related code (e.g. a toggle that triggers a network request) out of the hosting Activity into a separate module.

I'm looking for reference implementations or documents that describe how to implement such a behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVP pattern for this.

**View** in your case - it's `NavigationDraver`
**Presenter** - it's a simple interface which declared user iteractions.

For ex.

```
public interface DrawerPresenter {

    void toggleNetwork();

    void goOffline();

    void showSettings();
}
```

Actually, you just rebroadcasted all user actions to Presenter.
After this you can move `DrawerPresenter` and `Activity` logic to different modules.

Profit in this case :

- more clear logic
- agile architecture
- independence from UI

Comment: I don't see what I can gain by this approach. At the end of the day I still have to spawn a retained Fragment from my Activity in order to properly handle lifecycles. This could be easily avoided if the drawer itself was a Fragment. Correct me if I'm wrong, maybe I'm just not seeing the big picture here, since I never worked with this pattern.